# Centering Issue with CSS

Tags: html, css, center

On my website http://morxmedia.com/ if you zoom in the #container will lose centering with the navigation. I have lots of experience in css and I can't figure out how to fix this.
Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out..
I just set my main banner that had the width of 1100 px to width:100% and set the background image to center.
Then I made the header width the same as the content width.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have to use this trick:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

css ---

```
.wrapper {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}

.content {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
}
```

*** make sure your contents don't ave auto margins. if you ust have margins, use actual values.  the auto is no longer needed for centering.

Comment: Together with `#wrapper { text-align: center; }` on the wrapper and a reset for the content `#content { text-align: left; }` ?

Comment: Okay, I just thought a float-less design wouldgive you more control over the layout.

Comment: nice.  I usually use positioning but floats is better in this case because it can retain the flow.  don't forget `margin-left:-484px` or so.

Comment: I used the code example suggested and you can actually see it used live at http://morxmedia.com/ I still see the issue occurring though however.

Comment: got it to work -- instead of using margin: 0 auto on the contents of the container, give it actual right-left margins equal to the width those gutters with the tabs. margin: auto doesn't play nice with this trick.

Comment: .wrap {
width: 978px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}default.include.03b396.css:353
.wrap {

Comment: Hmm, I'm not understanding 100%. Haha. What to you mean set the width equal to the gutters with the tabs?

Comment: gah -- can't get it to work now.  i'll take another look when i get home from work.